# Only set property conditionally in QML

Tags: qml, qtquick2

I'm trying to set a property of a custom QML element conditionally. Meaning I only want to set it if something is true.

In this example I want to set `someProperty` when the application has a specific value, but if not, I want to let the object retain the original value. Also I want to let it behave like a binding. Meaning if the condition changes, it restores/sets the property again.

**main.qml**

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    MyObject {
        someProperty: (title == "different" ? "other_value" : 'undefined')
    }
}
```

**MyObject.qml**

```
Rectangle {

    property var someProperty: "original_value"

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.error("MyOject.someProperty: " + someProperty)
    }
}
```

So this prints:

> qml: MyOject.someProperty: undefined

I want it to print

> qml: MyOject.someProperty: original_value

So I have tried:

- `someProperty: (title == "different" ? "other_value")`: error
- `someProperty: (title == "different" ? "other_value" : someProperty)`: binding loop

I don't want to use any `onCompleted` kind of syntax because I want to retain the binding and not litter my code.

Answer (score 4):

You might use `States` together with `PropertyChanges` and set the State to be active, when the condition is met.

The `State`-System has the property that it saves restores the original state, once a `State`is left again.

Comment: Thanks, I looked it up but I don't think it is suitable. I have components with 5 or more properties to be set conditionally. This is not possible using states where only 1 is active.

Comment: @RvdK: You can define multiple *StateMachines* for each subset of properties that change together. Either you can define `Item`s which sole purpose is, to have a state that changes some properties in their parent nodes, or you can use `StateGroup`s. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-stategroup.html

Answer (score 1):

You could try with a `Binding` element

```
MyObject {
    id: myObject
}

Binding {
    target: myObject
    property: "someProperty"
    value: "other_value"
    when: title == "different"
}
```

Comment: Won't work. When the condition turns wrong again, the former value will not be restored.

Comment: Indeed, found this bug report: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-33444

Comment: @derM: only when the former value was not a binding, when it was a binding it was restored: property string someProperty: (true ? "original_value": "original_value")

Comment: I see now what you tried to communicate, but - the former value was bound. It is interesting, that for conditional bindings as in your comment's example, the binding persists. I would not have expected this, maybe because I learned, it does not work with non-conditional expressions.

Comment: @derM sure, but the requirement was to keep the original value or overwrite it. The question doesn't say anything about restoring any previous value.